# Unable to either install or use R

Tags: r

I am trying to install R on my system: MXLinux 5.16.0-5mx-amd64.

I have performed the instructions used to get the repositories with the latest version of R as given here: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-the-latest-r-programming-language-version-on-debian-11-bullseye/

To elaborate here, I:

1. Added GPG key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key '95C0FAF38DB3CCAD0C080A7BDC78B2DDEABC47B7'
```

2. Added the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian bullseye-cran40/'
```

3. Next I ran:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

4. This was followed by:

```
sudo apt install r-base -y
```

During the installation, I keep getting this warning: `rstudio missing or not found`, but continues on.

5. In the end, once the installation is done, in the terminal I run the command:

`R`

6. But get the error:

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3: undefined symbol: sgemv_thread_n
```

**My steps for mitigation:**

1. I have done `sudo apt install libopenblas-dev` and believe I have the lastest version.
2. I did `sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so` and got:

`update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for libblas.so`

3. I also did `sudo apt purge rstudio` to remove the warning about rstudio when installation occurs.
4. Ran `sudo apt autoremove` to remove unnecessary packages/files.

Is there a way to completely wipe out all R (and Rstudio) residuals and reinstall everything fresh?

**Additional info:**

1. When I run the command:

`sudo apt-get install r-base-dev r-base r-base-core`

I get the output:

```
r-base-core is already the newest version (4.2.2-1~bullseyecran.0).
r-base-dev is already the newest version (4.2.2-1~bullseyecran.0).
r-base is already the newest version (4.2.2-1~bullseyecran.0).
```

2. I have also referred to the info available on the R CRAN's official site for debian install of R and the information is identical to the link I have provided here.
3. When I run the command `locate libblas.so.3`, I get the output:

```
/etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu
/opt/libblas.so.3.9.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not following [the official Debian installation instructions](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/)?

Comment: Maybe I should add... I tried those instructions as well

Comment: Linking only, without mentioning the commands, is against the rules.
    Type the following 3 commands:
`sudo apt update`, `sudo apt install r-base -y`, `R`, and include for each the related ouptut.